# How can I say, "please let me give you an update "?

Tags: translation

I'm a bilingual Japanese/English speaker but I always have difficulty trying to describe "update" in Japanese. For example, when I'm visiting a company we work with regularly and want to say, "please let me give you an update (about our company)", I don't quite know how to say this. I think the closest might be something like, 「新しい方針について説明させて下さい」However, I'm not necessarily trying to inform them about a new policy but more about sharing what is new at our company. Any advice?

Comment: I'd think "以前の方針ですんが、更新されました". I believe the "以前" is a tip-off things have changed. ”更新" confirms this. Passive voice obscures who changed it ,which is more polite, as well as besides the point.

Comment: @david:  [Comments are not for Answers](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/q/593/78).

Comment: yes. i see. i gave a wrong answer. "方針" was not used correctly. my answer is bogus.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to just talk about what's new at the company, you might use [改新]{かい・しん} or [革新]{かく・しん}.  The "newness" of 新しい is already captured in those words, so you won't have to be redundant.

To be humble, you might want to preface it with [弊社]{へい・しゃ} ("our company").

As for the ending, it depends a little on the context of with whom you are speaking and when.  If you use 〜させて下さい, you are asking them to let you do it, but it almost sounds pathetic and/or like begging; like you're the `OTL` guy.

If you're in some kind of mutual meeting and they've shared about their company, and it's *clearly* your turn to share about your side, you should use 〜させていただきます.  "I receive you letting me do 〜".  It's a very common way to make humble statements.

Also, I would probably use 案内 instead of 説明, but again, it depends on the situation.  案内 is more for what they don't know.  説明 - to me - implies that they might already have some foreknowledge, and you're simply clearing up any confusion for them.

So I think I might say something like this:

> 弊社の改新につきまして、ご案内させていただきます。

Comment: Thanks, istrasci. I already use 弊社on a daily basis but was more focused on getting the right nuance for "update". I thank you for your suggestion, but I think 改新has a different nuance as it is more "renewing" something. So 「更新させていただきます」or「最新情報をお知らせします」to me, seems most appropriate. Again, thank YOU!